# How to add shift+ click multiselect functionality in extjs combobox

Tags: extjs, combobox

How to add shift plus click multiselect functionality in extjs combobox?

Comment: You can set `MultiSelect: true` if you're using an older version (before 5.1).  For newer versions, you could use a _tagfield_ or _multiselector_.

Comment: Thanks chrisuae for your reply.But what I need is that on selecting an item in the combobox and the pressing the shift key and selecting other item should select all the items between these two selections.I need it in a combobox for an old version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for ExtJS 5.1.3 / 6.0.2 / 6.2.0 
Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1jhv

```
Ext.define('Combo',{
    override: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    onBindStore: function(store, initial) {
        var me = this,
            picker = me.picker,
            extraKeySpec,
            valueCollectionConfig;

        if (store) {
            if (store.autoCreated) {
                me.queryMode = 'local';
                me.valueField = me.displayField = 'field1';
                if (!store.expanded) {
                    me.displayField = 'field2';
                }

                if (me.getDisplayTpl().auto) {
                    me.setDisplayTpl(null);
                }
            }
            if (!Ext.isDefined(me.valueField)) {
                me.valueField = me.displayField;
            }

            extraKeySpec = {
                byValue: {
                    rootProperty: 'data',
                    unique: false
                }
            };
            extraKeySpec.byValue.property = me.valueField;
            store.setExtraKeys(extraKeySpec);

            if (me.displayField === me.valueField) {
                store.byText = store.byValue;
            } else {
                extraKeySpec.byText = {
                    rootProperty: 'data',
                    unique: false
                };
                extraKeySpec.byText.property = me.displayField;
                store.setExtraKeys(extraKeySpec);
            }

            valueCollectionConfig = {
                rootProperty: 'data',
                extraKeys: {
                    byInternalId: {
                        property: 'internalId'
                    },
                    byValue: {
                        property: me.valueField,
                        rootProperty: 'data'
                    }
                },
                listeners: {
                    beginupdate: me.onValueCollectionBeginUpdate,
                    endupdate: me.onValueCollectionEndUpdate,
                    scope: me
                }
            };


            me.valueCollection = new Ext.util.Collection(valueCollectionConfig);

            me.pickerSelectionModel = new Ext.selection.DataViewModel({
                mode: me.multiSelect ? me.enableShiftSelect ? 'MULTI' : 'SIMPLE' : 'SINGLE',
                ordered: true,
                deselectOnContainerClick: false,
                enableInitialSelection: false,
                pruneRemoved: false,
                selected: me.valueCollection,
                store: store,
                listeners: {
                    scope: me,
                    lastselectedchanged: me.updateBindSelection
                }
            });

            if (!initial) {
                me.resetToDefault();
            }

            if (picker) {
                me.pickerSelectionModel.on({
                    scope: me,
                    beforeselect: me.onBeforeSelect,
                    beforedeselect: me.onBeforeDeselect
                });

                picker.setSelectionModel(me.pickerSelectionModel);

                if (picker.getStore() !== store) {
                    picker.bindStore(store);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Then create your combobox with `enableShiftSelect: true` and `multiSelect: true`.

```
// The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
    ]
});

// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    enableShiftSelect: true,
    multiSelect: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: Awesome... what version of ExtJS are you using?

Comment: Guillermo, is there any other way to do this, actually I need it to integrate it in a plugin which involves multicheck combobox. This has been built, only shift plus click part is left.

Comment: Ill need to see the plugin working to be able to help. Can you upload your code to a fiddle (https://fiddle.sencha.com)

Comment: Guilherme I am using a variant of this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dFEsc/16/    I need something like this http://www.levihackwith.com/adding-shiftclick-multi-select-capability-to-the-superboxselect-plugin/     but in my plugin instead of superBoxSelect plugin

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem seems to be. I just added the same override form this ticket and added enableShiftSelect: true to the combo config and it worked just fine. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1k11